# Using Javascript: How to create a 'Go Back' link that takes the user to a link if there's no history for the tab or window?

Tags: javascript, html

***EDIT-2:** None of the answers seem to work. Not even the one I previously marked as the answer of this question. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.*

First, I have googled for a how-to on creating a 'Go Back' link that allows the user to return to the previous page, and these are two ways of doing it:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">[Go Back]</a>
```

and...

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;">[Go Back]</a>
```

Which of these two is a better choice? And why? (Also, please shed some light on browser compatibility.)

That's one half of the question. Now if mine is the first page the user is visiting, the 'Go Back' link wouldn't work, right? (As there's no pre-existing history for the window or tab.) In that case, I want the link to fallback and take the user to http://example.com.

i.e. if history exists, the user is taken to the previous page, and if it doesn't he's taken to http://example.com.

How do I do that? Hope someone can help.

**EDIT:** Please note that I do not know JavaScript, so kindly make your answer explanative. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not

Comment: @ajax333221 - With all due respect — it's not. It's obvious if you read my question completely.

Comment: the problem is that you asked multiple things. But from the horizontal line to below, the dup will do exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @ajax333221 I didn't just ask for a go-back link, I also wanted it to redirect to a link if no history exists.

Comment: "I didn't just ask for a go-back link", well if actually read the dup, you will see they address the other issue as well

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You cannot check `window.history.length` as it contains the amount of pages in you visited in total in a given session:

> `window.history.length` (Integer)
>
> Read-only. Returns the number of elements in the session history, including the currently loaded page. For example, for a page loaded in a new tab this property returns 1. <sup>[Cite 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history)</sup>

Lets say a user visits your page, clicks on some links and goes back:

```
www.mysite.com/index.html <-- first page and now current page                  <----+
www.mysite.com/about.html                                                           |
www.mysite.com/about.html#privacy                                                   | 
www.mysite.com/terms.html <-- user uses backbutton or your provided solution to go back
```

Now `window.history.length` is 4. You cannot traverse through the history items due to security reasons. Otherwise on could could read the user's history and get his online banking session id or other sensitive information.

You can set a timeout, that will enable you to act if the previous page isn't loaded in a given time. However, if the user has a slow Internet connection and the timeout is to short, this method will redirect him to your default location all the time:

```
window.goBack = function (e){
    var defaultLocation = "http://www.mysite.com";
    var oldHash = window.location.hash;

    history.back(); // Try to go back

    var newHash = window.location.hash;

    /* If the previous page hasn't been loaded in a given time (in this case
    * 1000ms) the user is redirected to the default location given above.
    * This enables you to redirect the user to another page.
    *
    * However, you should check whether there was a referrer to the current
    * site. This is a good indicator for a previous entry in the history
    * session.
    *
    * Also you should check whether the old location differs only in the hash,
    * e.g. /index.html#top --> /index.html# shouldn't redirect to the default
    * location.
    */

    if(
        newHash === oldHash &&
        (typeof(document.referrer) !== "string" || document.referrer  === "")
    ){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            // redirect to default location
            window.location.href = defaultLocation;
        },1000); // set timeout in ms
    }
    if(e){
        if(e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
        if(e.preventPropagation)
            e.preventPropagation();
    }
    return false; // stop event propagation and browser default event
}
```

```
<span class="goback" onclick="goBack();">Go back!</span>
```

Note that `typeof(document.referrer) !== "string"` is important, as browser vendors can disable the referrer due to security reasons (session hashes, custom GET URLs). But if we detect a referrer and it's empty, it's probaly save to say that there's no previous page (see note below). Still there could be some strange browser quirk going on, so it's safer to use the timeout than to use a simple redirection.

**EDIT:** Don't use `<a href='#'>...</a>`, as this will add another entry to the session history. It's better to use a `<span>` or some other element. Note that `typeof document.referrer` is always `"string"` and not empty if your page is inside of a (i)frame.

See also:

- [W3C: HTML5: 5.4.2 The History interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#the-history-interface)

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about the comment — If the previous page starts to load or fully loads in a given time?

Comment: Well, it's more "if the current page hasn't been unloaded in a given time". Whenever your browser leaves the page.

Comment: This is the only thing that seems to be working, how sad, there's not one straight forward way.

Comment: Well, you could check whether the `history.length` is `1` and add a `window.location.hash = 'intropage'`. Then you could check whether your current hash is `intropage`. However, as you said, there's no straight forward way. And don't forget that this solution won't work if JavaScript is deactivated.

Comment: @Pacerier: So, when `window.goBack` gets used, it uses `history.back()`, which will leave the current context. If this happens _before_  the timeout expires (set in `setTimeout`), the user will happily go back in the history. If it _doesn't_ happen during those 1000ms, `window.location.href = ...` will redirect the user to a default page. Note that it's been three years since I've answered this question. I don't have time at the moment, but I can probably create an image which makes this a little bit more clear.

Comment: @Zeta, Ok I get the *hack* now. But this seems to be a very limited solution. For example, we couldn't do something like check if there's any "back history" left and hide the Back button altogether.

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes it's limited. So? It's, as you say, _a hack_. Unfortunately, current browsers and the HTML5 history API don't provide the necessary means to accomplish OP's original request.

Comment: @Zeta, Hopefully we can do it next time. 74k views to this page... people sure want this feature.

Answer (score 15):

check [`window.history.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history) or simply, `history.length`

**EDIT:** [some browsers start their history with 0, others with 1. adjust accordingly.](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-History-Length-Property.aspx)

if it has a value of 1, it means it's the first page in that window/tab - then you can have JS redirect you.

```
<script>
    function backAway(){
        //if it was the first page
        if(history.length === 1){
            window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/"
        } else {
            history.back();
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="backAway()">Back</a>
```

Comment: I do not know JavaScript, can you kindly provide me the actual code? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you need to check against `1`?, I think it is to `0`

Comment: MDN says a newly loaded page has a history.length of 1, check the link in the post

Comment: Something's probably wrong. It doesn't seem to work. Doesn't even show the link. :(

Comment: @Joseph : I'm sorry. It's my fault. Your code is working 100%. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: starting values vary by browser. check the browser before applying.

Comment: @Joseph But I want it to work properly on all browsers, at least IE8 and later. Any other way around?

Comment: then do object detection to know what browser the user is using, and evaluate the history accordingly http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html

Comment: @Joseph : I have found a way, using referrers. Please take a look at ajax333221's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9756201/1071413

Comment: @Joseph : If you can, please approve my edit to ajax333221's answer. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, **This will not work**. It could say 10 if you have "foward" entries, even while the backward entries are 0.

Answer (score 12):

both would work the same, its just two different methods to call the same function. Try the following:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();">[Go Back]</a>
```

Comment: Please take a look at my question again. I also want the link to take users to http://example.com if no history exists for the tab or window.

Comment: `<a href="history.length>0?javascript:history.back(): window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/';">[Go Back]</a>`

Comment: Are you sure it's correct? It doesn't seem to be working. I get this error — `This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/New%20folder/history.length%3E0?javascript:history.back():%20window.location%20=%20'http://www.mysite.com/';` Please check. Thanks.

Comment: ops sorry, like this: `<a href="javascript:history.length>0?history.back(): window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/';">[Go Back]</a>` javascript: goes first to tell href js must be executed.

Comment: There's one issue with using `history.length` as different browser have different values. Chrome and Firefox for example, use `1`. Please see Joseph's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9756193/1071413

Comment: The following will check if it knows how to do the "referrer" method (safari, ff, crhome).. If not (IE) it uses 0 `<a href="#" onclick="var i;if(document.referrer) {i=1} else {i=0}; history.length>i?history.back(): window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/';return false;">[Go back]</a>`

Comment: I would STRONGLY suggest putting the javascript code in the `onclick` attribute, so you can use the `href` attribute for the page you go to when no history exists.

Comment: @MrLister : None of the answers seem to be working (I did not check properly earlier). If you know JavaScript, please do put a tested answer.

Comment: @badlearner, take a look at this post, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873290/using-javascript-history-back-fails-in-safari-how-do-i-make-it-cross-browse

Comment: @CharasOverride Tried them all, no combination is working. :(

Comment: Damn, that is weird.. can you provide some info about your environment.. i.e: firefox under windows, etc.. ?

Comment: @badlearner OK, now what you should do is tell us exactly how you tested. Which operating system, which browser(s) and version number(s) etc. and what the exact results were (nothing; error; ended up on wrong page etc)

Comment: @MrLister and CharasOverride : I am on Windows 7, using the latest version of Chrome (v17.0.963.79). I tried two code variants (here: http://pastebin.com/znh65cjQ) among many others, and what happens is — I am being taken to http://example.com no matter what. Even if browser history exists in current window, clicking the 'Go Back' link isn't taking me back to the previous page — it just takes me to http://example.com

Comment: @CharasOverride : Plz see my previous comment (right above). I've provided the details you asked for.

Comment: @CharasOverride Can you please use pastebin? (I don't know JS and the code in your comment appears to be broken — unformatted)

Answer (score 8):

```
echo "<p><a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\" title=\"Return to previous page\">&laquo;Go back</a></p>";
```

Will go back one page.

```
echo "<p><a href=\"javascript:history.go(-2)\" title=\"Return to previous page\">&laquo;Go back</a></p>";
```

Will go back two pages.

Comment: This worked for me, you can see it in action here. https://supfort.com/wrong, click Go Back at the top right corner or the button to the left from Send Message Again button. By the way I am using go two pages back, just in case you did not notice. And it only works when you fill the form and you either get the wrong page or the thank you page. https://supfort.com/thanks

Answer (score 7):

The reason on using the `return:false;` is well explained on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event).

For the other issue, you can check for the [referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer) to see if it is empty:

```
    function backAway(){
        if (document.referrer == "") { //alternatively, window.history.length == 0
            window.location = "http://www.example.com";
        } else {
            history.back();
        }
    }

<a href="#" onClick="backAway()">Back Button Here.</a>
```

Comment: I do not know JavaScript, can you kindly provide me the actual code? Thanks.

Comment: But, there are two ways of doing it. I have the edit for your on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/EUuq9tH7 - - If you think it's okay, please add that to your answer. It will be a great reference for me. :) Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I didn't check properly before, but this doesn't seem to be working. Damn! This is getting tricky.

Answer (score 6):

**this seems to do the trick:**

```
function goBackOrGoToUrl() {    

    window.history.back();
    window.location = "http://example.com";

}
```

Call history.back() and then change the location. If the browser is able to go back in history it won't be able to get to the next statement. If it's not able to go back, it'll go to the location specified.

Answer (score 3):

The following code did the trick for me.

html:

```
<div class="back" onclick="goBackOrGoHome()">
  Back
</div>
```

js:

```
home_url = [YOUR BASE URL];

pathArray = document.referrer.split( '/' );
protocol = pathArray[0];
host = pathArray[2];

url_before = protocol + '//' + host;

url_now = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;


function goBackOrGoHome(){
  if ( url_before == url_now) {
    window.history.back();    
  }else{
    window.location = home_url;
  };
}
```

So, you use `document.referrer` to set the domain of the page you come from. Then you compare that with your current url using `window.location`.

If they are from the same domain, it means you are coming from your own site and you send them `window.history.back()`. If they are not the same, you are coming from somewhere else and you should redirect home or do whatever you like.

Comment: Brilliant! this really helped me, +1 thanks for the answer :D

Comment: I'm glad it was useful!

Answer (score 2):

Added a new answer to display the code formatted:

The thing is that you were checking for document.referer, because you were in ff it was returning always true, then it was navigating to http://mysite.com. Try the following:

```
function backAway(){
    if (document.referrer) {
        //firefox, chrome, etc..
        i = 0;
    } else {
        // under ie
        i = 1;
    }
    if (history.length>i)
    {
        // there are items in history property
        history.back();
    } else {
        window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I just tested this on firefox, doesn't take me to http://www.mysite.com/ this time. It takes me to previous page if history exists though. So, only one thing is working, either that or this.

Comment: And in chrome, it's not working at all. And IE9 it says, IE has blocked this site from running scrips or accessing Active X controls. :(

Comment: im not sure about firefox setting history.length to 1, you will have to check, so try to modify `i = 1` for `i = 0`

Comment: no it is not.. it is trivial ! can you please make me a favour ? add the following on top and check the alert message when there is no history back `alert(history.length);` on any browser you can..

Comment: `1` in latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera. `0` in Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. Thanks a lot for your time, and trying to help.

Comment: i removed the comment because as soon as i wrote i realized that could not be the issue.. im stunned that did not work.. but yeah, unless i dont get the hands on it, its difficult. Anyway if you keep on testing use the alert command and/or firebug for debuggin, cheers

Comment: hey there! you should give a try to `self.window.location` instead. i had one issue with window.location not refering well to the page i requested and adding `self` solved my problem.

Comment: Did you give up?.. because i still got more ideas in the tophat

Comment: Share away! My computer crashed the other day, so I was unavailable.

Comment: You can go use jQuery libraries so that it takes care of your backlink, check this tut http://www.electricfairground.com/2009/10/01/restoring-conventional-page-navigation-to-your-javascript-application-with-jquery-history-plugin/

Comment: I understood bits and pieces of the tut, but I don;t want to do any mistakes (I do not know JavaScript). It would be great if you can put that into an answer (or modify this answer perhaps?). Thanks.

Comment: Reading my last answer today, with my head properly awake, i realized there was a bug in the code. So, please give this a try before going further. The explanation is very simple. Safari, Chrome, etc.. use 0 as history.length, ie uses 1. In my previous answer i just wrote that if it was Safari use 1 where it had to use 0, and the other way around. Give a try to my recently modified answer, copy it as it is because i have already reedited.

Comment: This is weird. It worked the first time I tried in Chrome. Upon repeated tests, the link does nothing! (It also worked on Firefox - I don't have my windows laptop around to test Safari and IE.)

Comment: ok, at least there was some progress. Check it out in other browsers and report. You can use `alert(document.referrer);` to check wether a condition is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

simply use cookies to store your visited page list.

and apply some if else.

EDIT: also use ServerVariables HTTP_REFERER.

Comment: Using server variables as an alternative might be good most of the time to eliminate cross browser issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check both `document.referrer` and `history.length` like in my answer to similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645802/1145274

Answer (score 0):

How about using the history replacement function to add the site into the browsers history?

Try executing the following as soon as the window loads-

```
history.replaceState("example", "title", "http://www.example.com");
```

This should hopefully make it so even if it is the first page they have accessed, the URL you define in the code will be what they're taken to when they click back.

Answer (score 0):

You should use window variable - **window.referrer**. This variable contains the last page the user visited if they got to the current page by clicking a link
For example:

```
  function goBack() {
    if(document.referrer) {
      window.location.href = document.referrer;

      return;
    } 

    window.location.pathname = '/';
  }
```

This code redirect user to previous page if this is exist and redirect user to homepage if there isn't previous url