# The maximum value of 'window.history.length'

Tags: javascript

The value of `window.history.length` is very important in our project to detect the back button is clicked in the browser. However, I realized that `window.history.length` does not pass 50. How can I solve this?

Comment: This may well be a browser-specific limit anyway, and I'd think it'd keep the latest values and just remove the oldest at the head of the list. Are you monitoring the count specifically or the contents?

Comment: You could store the history in localStorage perhaps? :)

Comment: What is the history needed for?

Comment: @Rup I need count not the content.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy length is used to detect back button is clicked or not

Comment: @Rup How i will pop from window.history stack ?

Comment: @kml_ckr, This will not work. It could say 10 if you have "foward" entries, [even while the backward entries are 0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9757655/632951).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to detect "Back Button Clicked" via iFrames. You can find the answer at *[Browser Back Button Detection](http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/)*.

Comment: Yes I used that library. Thx for that.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on whether you need it to be persistent across sessions and surviving a clean of the user information (cache, localStorage, etc.), you might want to adopt different solutions.

One of the solutions could be to do something like this:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('history-changes-count'), 10);
  localStorage.setItem('history-changes-count', ++count);
};
```

Note that `onpopstate` gets invoked only after a user action. It doesn't work if you modify the history programmatically.

More on the subject: *[Window: popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate)*

Comment: Thanks. It looks clean solution

Comment: this seems like a clean and simple solution.

Comment: Caveat: localStorage is shared between tabs, so opening the same page in multiple tabs will mess up this solution.

Comment: Instead of localStorage, keep the count in the history state using `replaceState({count}, title, href)`. That will tie it to the browser history and keep it as long as the history is kept.

Comment: In addition to down voting my 6 years old answer consider adding an updated answer.