# window.pushState does not increment history length

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I have the following code that attempts to manipulate the `window.history` stack:

```
  console.log("before:" + window.history.length);
  window.history.pushState(null, null, '/page1');
  console.log("after:" + window.history.length);
```

This always prints the same in the `before` and `after`, even though I'm adding a state:

```
before:50
after:50
```

Why is `pushState` not incrementing the history length? By the way, length is always `50` even though I'm refreshing the page.

Comment: Works as it should for me: https://jsfiddle.net/0qrgesa3/

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Angular, it may be an Angular issue

Comment: This may vary by user agent. Some have a cap on the number of elements in the history. From [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/browsers.html#dom-history-pushstate): "User agents may limit the number of state objects added to the session history per page."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.history.length maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355549/window-history-length-maximum-value)

Comment: Firefox (maybe other browsers) impose a limit on the maximum value of `history.length`. By default in Firefox it's 50. What the semantics are of doing a `.pushState()` when the length is 50 is a hard topic to look for, but as far as I can tell it effectively "pushes" entries off the *bottom* of the list, so that there are still 50 entries but the "back" button does what you expect.