# Html button with location.href and document.referrer together

Tags: javascript, html, location, href, referrer

I am trying to make this work

```
<script>
document.write('<button onclick="location.href=' + document.referrer + '">Go back</button>');
</script>
```

It should be nothing but a simple "Back" button to the previsous page.
When I do it like an "a href" it works

```
<script>
    document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go back</a>');
</script>
```

but when trying tom ake it as a "button" it fails. The button is there but didnt navigate to the previsious page

Comment: I think the problem is with the brackets and quotes...Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also implement native back with:

```
window.history.back();
//in your onclick="history.back()"
//also can try with:
//javascript:history.go(-1)">
```

Or call a function that check if history.back() is available in the browser first else implement a custom back function/code as is showed here (I would prefer take out the code from the html just handle the onclick in my function)

[Using javascript history.back() fails in Safari .. how do I make it cross-browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873290/using-javascript-history-back-fails-in-safari-how-do-i-make-it-cross-browse)

For a robust solution check history.js:

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Answer (score 5):

Add another escaped quote into the href body (as well as a semicolon at the end, although I don't know if that would make a difference) and see if that works...

```
<script>
document.write('<button onclick="location.href=\'' + document.referrer + '\';">Go back</button>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the quotes around the URL in the href, so try escaping it like this (worked for me)

`document.write('<button onclick="location.href=\'' + document.referrer + '\'">Go back</button>');`