# Router.back() button in safari not working

Tags: safari, next.js, back-button

I'm currently making an mobile web application with next.js boilerplate.

My back button code is this.

```
import Router from 'next/router'

<button>
  <a href="#" onClick={() => Router.back()}>
    <span> some back button icon here </span>
  </a>
</button>
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with my html code but when clicking that button on
safari browser, it doesn't work. Anybody had same experience? or know the solution? or know why this is happening?
please share ;

FYI. I've tried major browsers like IE, Chrome, Firefox but only Safari don't work.

Comment: Have you tried onClick=Router.back() without the "()=>"?

Comment: Darrelk thanks for the opinion but If I do that, Router.back() function executes even when I don't click back button.

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873290/using-javascript-history-back-fails-in-safari-how-do-i-make-it-cross-browse)  I think this shows the core problem.

Answer (score 1):

this work for me:

```
import Router from 'next/router'
...
<button>
  <a href="#" onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); Router.back(); }}>
    <span> some back button icon here </span>
  </a>
</button>
```

A little late, but I'm sure someone needs it.