# How to check if we can go back in JS?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a directive in Angular that can go back if there is a history or go to a default route.
We can not test in JS if there is previous history.
So I make a redirection to the default route and call the history.back() function.

- Case 1 :
  there is not history, the history.back() function does nothing and the redirection to the default route is done.
- Case 2 :
  there is a history, the redirection to the default route starts but is canceled by the history.back() and the user is redirected to the previous page.

```
goBack() {      
        if(this.routerCommand) {
            this.router.navigate(this.routerCommand);
        }
        window.history.back();
    }
```

It works in all browsers except Safari.
I don't understand why ?

If someone can help me.
Thank's in advance.

Comment: Maybe it can helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873290/using-javascript-history-back-fails-in-safari-how-do-i-make-it-cross-browse

Answer (score 0):

Instead using *window.history* try to use Location. In your.component.ts:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) {}

goBack() {      
    if(this.routerCommand) {
        this.router.navigate(this.routerCommand);
    }
    this.location.back();
}
```

Note: it is important to import *Location* form *@angular/common*

Comment: Thank's for your answer.
Yes I tried to use this.location.back() instead of window.history.back() but the comportement was the same...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Your code will only got 1 case.
The case is: if `routerCommand` do `router.navigate` and then whatever is going on do `window.history.back();`

Next, You can check tab's history by command `History.length` (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/length)

Answer: I'm not absolutely know the answer. But if you curious about browser compatibility of any feature you can check on this site : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back#browser_compatibility

Comment: Thank's
The history.length return the length of the previous and next history, not only the previous history...